# How to optimize Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I code both Spring MVC and also .Net stuff, so I can have Visual Studio and Eclipse (STS) running on my Windows x64 machine.

What I've noticed is that the Eclipse seems really slow on compiles and a lot of other functions, whereas Visual Studio seems pretty quick.

Even more noticeable is when I look at the Processes in Task Manager, Visual Studio is taking up 200 Meg while Eclipse is holding on to a Gig of memory!

I don't want to be an Eclipse hater, since I think it has some really good features, but can anyone suggest how I can make it more efficient, or am I stuck with this sluggish IDE?  I've been thinking of switching to IntelliJ, but wanted to see if it was possible to tweak Eclipse to speed it up first.

Comment: Working fast for me... not sure what you are doing?

Comment: A gig seems unreasonably high. Are you using too many plugins? Some plugins are memory hogs. I assume you have gone through the the -Xms and -Xmx settings in your eclipse.ini file.

Comment: @Deep, not sure about -Xms and -Xmx in the .ini files, what can I tweak there?

Comment: @Code Monkey, unfortunately since it's Eclipse I have a bunch of plugins like Android, SVN, Maven, etc

Comment: @Mark: Hmm, ok. Not using Android here but Maven and Plug-in Development is installed on mine along with RCP.

Comment: @Mark This link should help. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini you can tweak the starting heap size and the max heap size and many other settings in the ini file in order to optimize your install. But like many others I suggest running as few plugins as possible. In the past I always tended to run Maven/Ant and other build and reporting tools from the command line. The integration is a nice to have but not always required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers that could help :

1. Make sure you are on 64 bit JDK and Eclipse to leverage your system.
2. Use the latest version of Eclipse. Indigo is what I am on currently.
3. Uninstall un-necessary plugins.
4. Try creating working sets and arrange your projects. Close down sets which you are not working on.
5. You can try switiching off Build automatically, but that would not be a great idea to catch build errors immediately.

Comment: Thanks Ajay.  I'm running all x64, running Helios, is there a big difference?  I only have open what I am working on.  I have build automatically set on, but I've set it so only the AJ files get built.

Comment: Helios should be fine, but its always good to be on the latest version. If you want to take this to the next level, try profiling eclipse using visualvm and find what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice is to install just as much of Eclipse as you need and not a plugin more. Eclipse platform and Java support is extremely light-weight and performs quite well. It's when you add other plugins (written with varying degrees of quality) is when you start having problems.

Comment: Konstantin, thanks, you are probably right, but the problem is that I need a bunch of plugins.  I'm coding Android, need the SVN plugins, have Roo, Selenium, Maven, all of which I need.

Comment: If you don't need all of these concurrently, you can try creating multiple installations tuned to particular usage patterns. The bottom lines is that one or more of these plugins is causing your Eclipse to drag. The only way to resolve that problem is to identify the plugin or plugin that's causing issues and not use it or sandbox it in a separate install that you only reach for when you have to. Also, once you know which plugin is causing the problem, you can report the issue to the vendor.

Comment: Thanks, that could be an option.  I've also noticed that h2 in-memory DB is quite a hog as well.